# Why does it work locally and not remotely?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I put the website into aws cloud and the website is written in php. When using the command
`$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $database);` the page does not work. How do we use`$conn = new mysqlit($server, $user, $pass, $database);` the website works, but it does not connect to the base any longer. Is there any difference in these commands?

Comment: I've never seen `mysqlit` before. Is that a typo or custom sqlite driver?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of these commands is the same, but they are two very different approaches to the same goal. Whereas mysqli_connect is procedural, 'new mysqli' is creating an object.

In practice, this means that mysqli_connect can be used with other procedural commands (such as mysqli_query). The OOP way of doing it, with an object, is now the preferred method but does force you to use the object to communicate with the database.

Object oriented (OOP):

```
$conn = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $database);
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM somewhere");
```

Procedural:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $database);
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM somewhere");
```

However, I would strongly advise to use the object oriented way for a more future proof application. (I believe that the procedural method is actually deprecated.)

More info and examples can be found here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I am not able to start it procedurally an aws rds?

Comment: Possibly. Try running phpinfo() to check the version and extensions.

Answer (score -1):

be sure that the password and username is the same as the one in the aws cloud